# How To know if content of the ckeditor is changed

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How To know if content of the ckeditor is changed. I need to call a function in javascript whenever the content of the ckeditor is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following functions and have worked fine for me. I was using CKEDITOR 4 and in my case i have made a call back function based on the 'checkDirty() s' return value.

[checkDirty()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-checkDirty)

[resetDirty()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-resetDirty)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Comment: You can use those functions to verify whether the content has changed, but you need another way to be notified of when to check (unless you want to check it continuosly and kill the performance of your page)

Answer (score -1):

May be you want [this](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) plugin?